# Algebraic operations on hypergeometric functions

Tags: hypergeometric-function

In the solution of a problem in physics I came across the expression
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}, \quad f(x)={}_2F_1\left(\frac12,1;\frac d2;-x^2\right)$$
where $d$ is a integer. 
I was wondering if this can be expressed as a hypergeometric series or not. In literature, people argue that this is clearly impossible, never give a proof though.

If we expand the denominator, we get a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(x)^k$
and therefore can express the term $f(x)^k$ as a ${}_{p}F_{q}$ hypergeometric function with coefficients $p$ and $q$ increasing with $k$. This is probably not the way to go, then.

I know hypergeometric functions have a quite rich algebra, but I couldn't find any helpful identity in my textbooks (Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, Abramowitz and Stegun, Rainville or Erdélyi). Does someone know a technique or a more solid reference that could answer the question and possibly the expression of $g$ if there is such an hypergeometric expansion ?

Comment: For $d=3$, Wolfram Alpha [gave](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric2F1%5B1%2F2%2C+1%2C+3%2F2%2C+-x%5E2%5D) $f(x) = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x}$ and I found [this](http://www.johndcook.com/HypergeometricFunctions.pdf#page=3) list of identities to confirm the result. However, other $d$ values gave quite different results.

Comment: @Anant. Thank you for searching. The function $g$ with $d=3$ is exactly the result I am fighting with, but I already knew $f$. Is there a hypergeometric expansion for $g(x)=\arctan x/(x-\arctan x)$ ?

Comment: Quite late to the show but ...  for x=0 the denominator is zero and the numerator is one; for all hypergeometric functions.   Thus, g(0)=inf wouldn't qualify.   But allowing a little more flexibility in the formulation raises a whole realm of interesting possibilities.